# Ruby on rails will not update attributes of a profile model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my user model updating works perfectly fine...
No matter what I do in my profiles model,controller view my database won't update. In my user model I had the same issue but found out it was because I needed a password field. In this however I don't as I don't have any validation set in the profile model.

I have no idea what is going on. The logs in terminal show that the current_user.id is being found and I'm using that result to find the user_id in my profiles table and that works. Updating won't happen though.

What could be wrong?

Kind regards

Logs

```
--- &id001 !ruby/object:Profile 
_already_called: 
  ? 
    - :autosave_associated_records_for_user
    - :user
  : false

_start_transaction_state: 
  :id: 1
  :new_record: false
  :destroyed: false
  :level: 1
aggregation_cache: {}

association_cache: {}

attributes: 
  id: 1
  user_id: 1
  motd: Success is guaranteed!
  first_name: Foo
  last_name: Bar
  birthday: 
  star_sign: 
  gender: 
  marital_status: 
  sexual_preference: 
  racial_background: 
  location: 
  profile_url: 
  about_me: 
  height: 
  body_type: 
  eye_colour: 
  drugs: 
  alcohol: 
  cigarettes: 
  likes: 
  dislikes: 
  bad_habits: 
  food: 
  music: 
  television: 
  book: 
  animal: 
  place: 
  possesion: 
  profile_visits: 
  created_at: 2012-01-07 23:02:29.228500
  updated_at: 2012-01-07 23:02:29.228500
attributes_cache: 
  birthday: 
  created_at: 2012-01-07 23:02:29.228500 Z
  updated_at: 2012-01-07 23:02:29.228500 Z
changed_attributes: {}

destroyed: false
errors: !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Errors 
  base: *id001
  messages: !omap 
    - :motd: []

    - :first_name: []

    - :last_name: []

marked_for_destruction: false
new_record: false
previously_changed: !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess {}

readonly: false
relation: 
validation_context: 
Profile updated
--- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
utf8: "\xE2\x9C\x93"
_method: put
authenticity_token: YZwwOx5CqfKTfsybXE4NH2o2dTg4asKZZu6QOR9Y3Zo=
profile: !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
  motd: Success is guaranteed!
  first_name: Foo
  last_name: Bar
commit: update
action: update
controller: profiles
id: "1"
```

Routes

```
  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :passwords
  resources :profiles


  root :to                   => "users#new"
  match 'success'            => "users#success"
  match 'login'              => "sessions#new"
  match 'logout'             => "sessions#destroy"
  match 'reset_password'     => "passwords#new"
  match 'setup_new_password' => "passwords#edit"
  match 'settings', :to      => "users#settings"


  match "/settings/account", :to => "users#account"
  match "/settings/edit_profile", :to => "profiles#edit_profile"


  match '/:username', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

Model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

   attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :motd


end
```

Profiles_controller

```
    def new
    @user = Profile.new 
    end

    def update
        @user = Profile.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
        if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        render 'edit_profile'
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated" 
        else
        redirect_to root_path
        end
      end

  def edit

  end

  def edit_profile
  @user = Profile.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
  end

end
```

View

```
<div id="formo"> <%= form_for @user,  do |f| %>

<%= f.text_field :motd, :placeholder => "motd"  %><br />
<%= f.text_field :first_name, :placeholder => "fname"  %><br />
<%= f.text_field :last_name, :placeholder => "lname"  %><br />

<%= f.submit 'update' %><br />
<% end %>
<%= debug(@user) %>
<div class="notify">
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
          <%= content_tag :div, msg, :class => "#{name}" %>
    <% end %>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

To:

```
if @user.update_attributes(params[:profile])
```

Also you might want to rename that instance variable to `@profile` so you don't get confused.

Comment: That actually hurt! After all these hours it was that. So basically the symbol in params refers to the model in question? Thanks.

Comment: Yes the key name in the params hash comes from the name of the class of the object you are referring to. The form builder is what is setting that up. `<%= form_for @user,  do |f| %>` <- That line

Comment: @GregoryHouse Always print your params. `<%= params%>` in your views or in your controller as well. When you print in your views, you will know the hash, its values and keys.You can then check it in your browser itself. When controller, keep checking your `/log/development.log` or your server for information. That would give you a detailed idea of whats in params and what do you need explicitly.